# Issue with SDSS.get spectra in AstroPy

Tags: python, astropy

I wrote the below code about 6 months ago, and it seemed to work fine. Now, however, I get the following::

~/astroconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroquery/sdss/**init**.py:28: UserWarning: Experimental: SDSS has not yet been refactored to have its API match the rest of astroquery (but it's nearly there).
    warnings.warn("Experimental: SDSS has not yet been refactored to have its API "

~/astroconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroquery/sdss/core.py:857: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for the system default.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

~/spectra/plot_spectra.py in <module>()
 34 xid = SDSS.query_region(pos, spectro=True,radius=2*u.arcsec)
 35 print(xid)
---> 36 j_eleven = SDSS.get_spectra(matches=xid)
 37 
 38 

~/astroconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroquery/sdss/core.py in get_spectra(self, coordinates, radius, matches, plate, fiberID, mjd, timeout, cache, data_release, show_progress)
613                                                mjd=mjd, timeout=timeout,
614                                                data_release=data_release,
--> 615                                                show_progress=show_progress)
616 
617         if readable_objs is not None:

~/astroconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astroquery/sdss/core.py in get_spectra_async(self, coordinates, radius, matches, plate, fiberID, mjd, timeout, get_query_payload, data_release, cache, show_progress)
585             link = linkstr.format(
586                 base=conf.sas_baseurl, dr=data_release,
--> 587                 instrument=row['instrument'].decode().lower(),
588                 run2d=run2d, plate=row['plate'],
589                 fiber=row['fiberID'], mjd=row['mjd'])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

error. Not sure what I did wrong/differently...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astroML.plotting import setup_text_plots

from astroquery.sdss import SDSS
from astropy import coordinates as coords
import astropy.units as u

## Find a spectrum using astroquery
pos = coords.SkyCoord('165.24045d -0.88458d', frame='icrs')
xid = SDSS.query_region(pos, spectro=True,radius=2*u.arcsec)
print(xid)
j_eleven = SDSS.get_spectra(matches=xid)
```

Comment: You should add a bit more (or just the full) traceback; not just a single error line.

Comment: Any change that you are mixing up Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: @Evert Have added the full traceback. And have always used Python 3. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably a bug in astroquery. I just ran it locally, after upgrading astroquery, and while I do get a deprecation warning (which is something to be fixed on the astroquery side), the code works fine for me.

Comment: [Here's the commit that fixed your issue](https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/commit/4724960bdd5075245e0fbdae5f05421cdf107d01#diff-58525516e5e2c6161b576488eaa9303a). Fix was from June 4, 2017, which was around version 0.3.5. Current version is 0.3.7.